# SQL count asset inventory

Tags: mysql

In sql help i have 3 tables, table one is asset table which is as follow

| id | asset_code | asset_name | asset_group | asset_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | computer | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | A002 | keyboard | 6 | 4 |

and another table is asset_allocation

| id | asset_id | allocated_quantity | allocated_location | returned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | IT office | no |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | main hall | yes |

the last table is asset_liquidated which will present assets that are no longer going to be used

| id | asset_id | liquidated_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

Now lets say that i have 7 computer out of which 2 are allocated but not returned and i have 4 keyboards out of which 1 is allocated and it is returned back and 1 computer is liquidated means it is never going to be used
so now here i want to join these 3 tables and find inventory of my current stock in hand.

Now this is the query now i need to add this
`where asset_allocation.returned is enum no` inside this query

```
SELECT id,asset_code, asset_name, asset_group, asset_quantity,allocated_quantity,liquidated_quantity,
       asset_quantity - COALESCE(AA.allocated_quantity, 0) - COALESCE(AL.liquidated_quantity, 0) available_quantity
  FROM asset A
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT asset_id, SUM(allocated_quantity) allocated_quantity
               FROM asset_allocation
              GROUP BY asset_id) AA ON A.id = AA.asset_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT asset_id, SUM(liquidated_quantity) liquidated_quantity
               FROM asset_liquidated
              GROUP BY asset_id) AL ON A.id = AL.asset_id;
```

Comment: You've already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271639/sql-count-inventory). Please edit your original question.

Comment: OP already asked this question with less context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271639/sql-count-inventory

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is adding WHERE returned = 'no' in your first JOIN like so:

```sql
SELECT id,asset_code, asset_name, asset_group, asset_quantity,allocated_quantity,liquidated_quantity,
           asset_quantity - COALESCE(AA.allocated_quantity, 0) - COALESCE(AL.liquidated_quantity, 0) available_quantity
      FROM asset A
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT asset_id, SUM(allocated_quantity) allocated_quantity
                   FROM asset_allocation
                   WHERE returned = 'no'
                  GROUP BY asset_id) AA ON A.id = AA.asset_id
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT asset_id, SUM(liquidated_quantity) liquidated_quantity
                   FROM asset_liquidated
                  GROUP BY asset_id) AL ON A.id = AL.asset_id;
```

That changes the available quantity for keyboard from 3 to 4 for me

your query:[image]

vs. mine:
[image]